# What is the best nosql database to store files contain only integer lists

Tags: database, mongodb, database-design, redis, nosql

I have over 60000 files ready to be stored in a nosql database. Each of them contains a certain number of lines, every line has integers with quite different scales. The later queries will find lines according to the line index, for example, look for the lists of line 2, 3, 5. I am quite new in nosql area, I don't know which nosql database would be the best to do it? Since I read that, Redis uses Key-value, while mongodb might good for json files. However, if the json file has a structure like `{key: "1", value: "12,24,57,865,567,4214314,436346,235,2341,2431,240978,324555"}`, for me it seems to be the same as the concept of Redis.

Furthermore, I will read the data in C, for memory allocating, I need to indicate the number of integers in a line as well. Would it be good if the structure looks like this: `{key: "1", value: "12,24,57,865,567,4214314,436346,235,2341,2431,240978,324555", num:"12"}`?

Comment: Redis holds all data in memory. If the size of an application's data is too large for that, then Redis is not an appropriate solution and Redis it's mainly performance focused.  How about your total files sizes?

Comment: Both MongoDB and Redis would do.  If you need performance, go Redis, otherwise, go MongoDB. For redis, you can use hash structure, {key:"fileName","value":[{"1"(line number):"1234"},{"2":""},{"3":"1111111"}]  } . This is a file with three lines. (the second line is empty)

Comment: @Li-Tian Hey, the total size of the files are about 700GB. the RAM is less than 150GB. so I guess Redis would not work then. I also would like to ask, if there is no sever cluster available, is that possible to deal with such large data in one server with the scale of RAM？

Comment: @AwesomeHunter As Li. mentioned, that Redis loads all data into memory, where my RAM is not enough for my data size, I think then I would have to choose mongoDB. So the structure `{key: "1", value: "12,24,57,865,567,4214314,436346,235,2341,2431,240978,324555", num:"12"}` would be good for my application? Would that then be easy for C to read lists?

Comment: @Erwin Zangwill,  Redis support cluster, but for your data type which is the file has larger size and not very high frequently read and write,  use redis cluster make things is too expensive, cost too much on the hardware and add unnecessary complexity for deployment and maintain

Comment: I took a look at MongoDB, your use case seems to be perfect for it. 1.MongoDb is disk based, so doesn't take too much precious memory. 2.MongoDB is about 100 faster than relational database in simple key-value quering.  I would store your data as {"fileName":"your file name","line_1":"line_1_content", "line_3":"line_3_content", ... , } then build an index on  "fileName" field.

Comment: Trying to update my comment above. After more research, I've concluded that PostgreSql is a better alternative to MongoDB. It doesn everything MongoDb does, including storing JSON, offers more feature and has better performance.

Comment: @AwesomeHunter as for the data structure, if my ram is way less than the data size, would it help, if every file is mapped to collections? So that later I can  query on several small collections instead of reading on one larger collection, does it make any difference in Mongodb?

Comment: @Li-Tian so that is actually not need to use cluster even with mongoDB?